# How to cache mp3 file in PhoneGap?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, html, cordova

I've a web app which uses HTML5 player to play audio mp3 files hosted on the server. I want to use PhoneGap to convert it to iPhone/Android apps. I want users to cache the audio files on the device. It would be really nice if I can somehow encode it and save it on the device rather than flat mp3 files. Just wondering that how can I do on iPhone/Android using PhoneGap.

Comment: Download and save. Don't go through all this sillyness. READ THE FAQs. Here is one [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)